# What type of battery is used in Oura ring?

Tags: batteries, wearable

What type of battery is used in Oura ring, and how many mAh is available? I am not sure how does Oura ring manage to claim up to 7 days of battery life. Should not using an LED and BLE connection in continuous mode drain the battery before 7 days that they claim?

Comment: Link datasheet pls.

Comment: *Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design.* AND *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oura website says LiPo battery, either 15mAh or 22mAh depending on the model.

They obviously save power by not keeping LED or BLE on the whole time.